# Как обработать нажатия ImageButton в ListView Android

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Я создал список, элементы которого соответствуют layout:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Time"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/percentage_text"
    android:text="Percentage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/time_text"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Далее для обработки элементов списка создаю свой адаптер и переопределяю в нем метод getView(...)

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private ArrayList<ProgressTimer> mTimers;
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_row_template, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    mTimers = new ArrayList<ProgressTimer>(values.length);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_template, parent, false);
    ProgressBar Progress = (ProgressBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    TextView Time = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.time_text);
    TextView Percentage = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.percentage_text);
    Percentage.setText(values[position]);
    ImageButton Button1 = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    ImageButton Button2 = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button_2);

    ProgressTimer timer = new ProgressTimer(Progress, Percentage, Time,
            Button1, Button2, 60000);

    return rowView;
}
```

}

Класс ProgressTimer (кроме хранения данных из элемента списпка (2 кнопки, прогрес бар и 2 TextView), нужен для запуска в новом потоке таймера (прогресс которого отображает ProgressBar). Поэтому он расширяет класс Runnable и в нем переопределен метод run:

```
public class ProgressTimer implements Runnable {

private ProgressBar mProgress;

private TextView mProcentage;
private TextView mTime;

private ImageButton mButton1;
private ImageButton mButton2;

protected int mCoolDown;

protected int progress;

public ProgressTimer (ProgressBar Progress, TextView Procentage, TextView Time,
                       ImageButton Button1, ImageButton Button2, int CoolDown)
{
    mProgress = Progress;
    mProcentage = Procentage;
    mTime = Time;
    mButton1 = Button1;
    mButton2 = Button2;
    mCoolDown = CoolDown;

    progress = 0;
    mProgress.setProgress(progress);

    mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            progress = 0;
            run();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (progress < 100){
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                wait(mCoolDown / 100);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        progress++;
        mProgress.setProgress(progress);
    }
}
```

}

В конструкторе класса я пытаюсь проводить обработку нажатия второй кнопки, но при нажатии на неё в приложении, приложение зависает (если идти дебагом, то функция run() вызывается в момент создания. Что я делаю не так, и как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запуск функции `run()` не запускает новый поток, вы остаетесь все в том же UI потоке и `while`+`wait` вешают его наглухо.

Ваша задача запустить отдельный поток, внутри него генерировать события для обновления прогресса, вызывать метод обновления прогресса в главном потоке. Псевдокод:

```
@UiThread
void btnClick(){
  new Thread(new Runnable(){ // Запускаем новый поток
      @Override
      public void run(){
         while (true){ 
            Thread.sleep(1000); // ждем секунду
            progress.post(new Runnable(){ // вызываем метод в UI потоке
                updateProgress();
            });
         }
      }
  }).start();
}

@UiThread
void updateProgress(){
    progress.setProgress(progress.getProgress()+1);
}
```

Вот [gist](https://gist.github.com/ivanovsuper/437675eb44754713107329ddb1ef6020) в ваших терминах.

Следует иметь в виду, что пауза в секунду, не обязательно будет именно секундной, она будет не менее секунды, но скорее всего более. Я бы посмотрел другие решения. Например, если прогресс обновляется при приеме данных из сети, то использовать колбэки из потока загрузки данных. Если это таки таймеры со временным отсчетом, то использовать один TimerTask и обновлять нужные элементы списка по текущему времени минус время запуска, а интервал не так важен. В общем все зависит от задачи, принцип работы с потоками один.

Answer (score 0):

Я не думаю, что использование `run();` по нажатию кнопки хорошая идея. В андроиде есть уйма классов для создания многопоточности: AsyncTask, AsyncTaskLoader, Loader, Handler.

Просто реализовывать "сырой" поток при функционале андроида не комильфо, на мой взгляд. Так что попробуйте использовать другие средства, думаю, проблема разрешится сама собой.